# Are small competitions allowed?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, on-site-contests

I was puzzling: "What is the shortest proof of $\exists x \forall y (P(x) \to P(y)) $?"  (a variation of the drinkers paradox see [Proof of Drinker paradox](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807092/proof-of-drinker-paradox)) given a certain set of inference rules and using natural deduction.

I managed to proof it in 23 lines, but I am not sure if this is the shortest possible proof.

That made me think maybe I could turn it into a little competition and offer say 200 reputation as reward for the shortest proof.

Would such a (competition) question be allowed?

Comment: The question should be asked on main with a bounty of 200 attached.

Comment: Posted the question see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/812949/small-competition-who-comes-up-with-the-shortest-proof-of-exists-x-foral wil send a bounty soon, ps don't think that it is an easy competition.

Comment: bounty set, let the game begin :)

Comment: Sounds like code golf. Cue proofgolf.stackexchange.com